# Dataset.readxml() only adds tags that appear once

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

I have written this code in c# to read an xml file (I will provide a snippet at the bottom)

Code:

```
    string filePath = "movies.xml";
    movieDataSet.ReadXml(filePath, XmlReadMode.InferTypedSchema);
    movieList.DataSource = movieDataSet;
    movieList.DataMember = "movie";
```

XML File:

```
<movielist>
<movie>
    <title>Adventures of Casanova </title>
    <year>1948</year>
    <length>83 min</length>
    <certification>Approved</certification>
    <director>Roberto Gavaldn</director>
    <rating>1</rating>
    <genre>Action</genre>
    <genre>Adventure</genre>
    <genre>History</genre>
    <genre>Romance</genre>
    <genre>War</genre>
    <actor>Arturo de C  rdova</actor>
    <actor>Lucille Bremer</actor>
    <actor>Turhan Bey</actor>
    <actor>John Sutton</actor>
    <actor>George Tobias</actor>
</movie>
<movie>
    <title>Amazon Quest </title>
    <year>1954</year>
    <length>75 min</length>
    <director>Steve Sekely</director>
    <rating>7</rating>
    <genre>Action</genre>
    <genre>Drama</genre>
    <actor>Tom Neal</actor>
    <actor>Carole Mathews</actor>
    <actor>Carole Donne</actor>
    <actor>Don Zelaya</actor>
    <actor>Ralph Graves</actor>
</movie>
<movie>
    <title>American Ninja 3: Blood Hunt </title>
    <year>1989</year>
    <length>89 min</length>
    <certification>R</certification>
    <director>Cedric Sundstrom</director>
    <rating>7</rating>
    <genre>Action</genre>
    <genre>Drama</genre>
    <actor>David Bradley</actor>
    <actor>Steve James</actor>
    <actor>Marjoe Gortner</actor>
    <actor>Michele B. Chan</actor>
    <actor>Yehuda Efroni</actor>
</movie>
</movielist>
```

I noticed the only tags being read are title, year, length, certification, director, rating which occur just once in within a movie. What could I be doing wrong? I have tried different XmlReadMode's and InferTypedSchema seems to be the one closest to solving my problem of adding the xml data to a dataset

Comment: You have to fix your XML. Group your actors and genre, in another tag like `<actors><actor>....</actor><actor>....</actor></actors>`

Comment: something like this: 
<actor><actor>Yehuda Efroni</actor></actor> for each actor?
I tried that and I still get the same result

Comment: NO. The main tag should be `<actors>` with a `s`, or anything for that matter which should specify a group.

Comment: I see. This didn' work for me. Is there a different way to read xml tags with multiple values in c#?

Comment: Maybe the problem is with your `movieList`?  If I read your Xml into a [`DataSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [write it back out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135426%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) using [`XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.xmlwritemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), then all the data is there and the schema looks good.  How are you formatting the data for display?

Comment: I found a way to use breakpoints to view the state of my dataset and I noticed there were individual tables for movies and genres identified by movie_id. So my lesson is that the readxml creates multiple tables for those kinds of tags